# Wordpress gallery in portfolio isn't shown when the shortlink is used

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I have a wordpress 3.9.1 installed with the Brooklyn theme pack.
I have several posts with the gallery of images inside.
When navigated through usual access:

http://soundsup.pro -> our releases -> Viza (first, red one),

the gallery works fine.

But when I am trying to use the direct link:

http://soundsup.pro/portfolio-item/viza-made-in-chernobyl/

the gallery is not shown.

Any ideas why is that and how to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in the theme. You should contact the theme owner/support to solve this issue.
If you customize the theme on your own, you will not be able to update it in future.